# Create custom datagridview's Column type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i just create a custom control, i want this control implement to datagridview's column.

but how? is it possible?

[image]

for example, i want add my column type like "DataGridViewCustomTextBoxColumn"

---

this is my current code.

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {

            Connection.ConnectionClose();
            Connection.ConnectionOpen();

            var source = new List<string>();
            string queryItem = "SELECT * FROM ITEM ";              

            Connection.command = new OleDbCommand(queryItem, Connection.conn);
            Connection.command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            AutoCompleteStringCollection kode = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            reader = Connection.command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //kode.Add(reader["code"].ToString());
                    source.Add(reader["code"].ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Data not Found");
            }
            reader.Close();
            //ComboBox txtBusID = e.Control as ComboBox;
            TextBox kodeTxt = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (kodeTxt != null)
            {
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = kode;
                kodeTxt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            }

        }
  }
```

what i tried.. like this.

```
 AutoCompleteTextBoxSample.AutoCompleteTextbox kodeTxt = e.Control as AutoCompleteTextBoxSample.AutoCompleteTextbox;
                if (kodeTxt != null)
                {
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
                    kodeTxt.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                }
```

then my autocomplete is not working anymore

What i want is just like this.

[image]

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Template Fields for this as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

One of the Template Fields will be your custom control.

This will involve writing code, rather than using the GUI.

Comment: am i possible to implement this `AutoCompleteTextBox` to datagridview's column? https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251110/AutoComplete-TextBox-with-substing-search-similar

Comment: I believe you can do this: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/autogridview.htm

Comment: am i missing something?

Comment: I don't understand.  What is blank? Can you post the code of your template fields?

Comment: thats my project, please see `SalesOrder.cs` , what i mean blank is when i type something, my list is not appear